# Get best parameters for TrainValidationSplit scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am using the Spark Scala ML API and I am trying to pass a pipeline ALS model to the TrainValidationSplit.  The code executes but I am unable to retrieve the best parameters...thoughts?

```
val alsPipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(idIndexer , modelIndexer, als))

val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder().
    addGrid(als.maxIter, Array(5, 10)).
    addGrid(als.regParam, Array(0.01, 0.05, 0.1)).
    addGrid(als.implicitPrefs).
    build()

val tvs = new TrainValidationSplit().
                setEstimator(alsPipeline).
                setEvaluator(new RegressionEvaluator().
                                    setMetricName("rmse").
                                    setLabelCol("purchases").
                                    setPredictionCol("prediction")).
                setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid).
                setTrainRatio(0.75)

val alsModel = tvs.fit(trainALS)
```

Comment: If  the provided solution solves your problem, [please accept and upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)  the answer to close the Q, otherwise please comment on why it doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the `rmse` for each parameter in your grid using:

```
alsModel.getEstimatorParamMaps.zip(alsModel.avgMetrics)
```